# jQuery doesn't work in the aspx file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

The JavaScript, which I found on stackoverflow doesn't work in my code but it works in the jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rxLg0bo4/9/
This is how i use the inline jQuery in my code:

```
<nav id="menu">
<script type="text/javascript">


$('.menu_link').hover(function () {
    $("#pnlSubmenu").slideDown('slow');
});
$('#pnlSubmenu').on("mouseenter", function () {
    $(this).show();
});
$('#pnlSubmenu').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).hide();
});
$('.menu_link').mouseleave(function () {
    $("#pnlSubmenu").hide();
});
            </script>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlMenu" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlSubmenu" runat="server">

                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>


            </asp:Panel>
        </nav>
```

This is what I wrote in my head:

```
    <script src="/Scripts/auto-rotate.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/key-nav.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It should make the dropdown menu working, but I think the jQuery doesn't get executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JavaScript is executed directly, while the elements are not rendered yet, therefor there are no elements to add events to.
Try putting your code inside [document.ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) function.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.menu_link').hover(function () {
        $("[id$=pnlSubmenu]").slideDown('slow');
    });
    $('[id$=pnlSubmenu]').on("mouseenter", function () {
        $(this).show();
    });
    $('[id$=pnlSubmenu]').mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).hide();
    });
    $('.menu_link').mouseleave(function () {
        $("[id$=pnlSubmenu]").hide();
    });
});
```

Because you're using webforms, the id's of the elements get changed. Like others here suggested, you could counter that. You could also change your jQuery code like above.

Comment: This method is not working and I think you forgot a clamp at the end.

Comment: @aha364636 You are correct, I forgot to close the function correctly. Also, because you are using webforms, the id's of the elements get changed, which you can counter by methods others here suggested. You could also change your jQuery code like above.

Comment: What do I have to do with the .menu_link because this also gets generated?

Comment: Nothing, because that's a `class` selector. And CSS classes won't be changed by ASP.

Comment: I tried the exact same thing, still not working.

Comment: Solved it, my CSS was not quite right.

Comment: Great! Good you found the problem.

Answer (score 4):

As You are using ASP.NET Controls generated ID of elements will be different. You should use [Control.ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=vs.110).aspx) Property.

> Gets the control ID for HTML markup that is generated by ASP.NET.

Also wrap your code in [document-ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler.

> Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

*Use*

```
 $(function () {
    $('#<%=pnlSubmenu.ClientID %>').click(function () {
        //Rest of the code
    })
 })
```

Comment: please refer https://api.jquery.com/ready/ for more detail

Comment: and i guess stack order of js files are also needs to be updated as there are multiple jquery libraries added but below the other libraries.

Answer (score 1):

The client side IDs of controls are different from server side IDs in asp.net. Some extra characters get appended before the ID. The best solution is to set `class` to your controls and access them in `jquery` with class selector.

OrElse you can try the following solution:

```
$('.menu_link').hover(function () {
    $("#pnlSubmenu").slideDown('slow');
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $("#pnlSubmenu").hide();
});

$("[id$='pnlSubmenu']").on("mouseenter", function () {
    $(this).show();
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work. Where can I check if it's gets executed?

Comment: Sorry my code had little spelling mistake. This will work for sure now.
Anyways I see you have already accepted an answer. Maybe this helps someone else

Comment: Why did you write .on("mouseenter" you could also write .mouseenter.

Comment: Both are correct. I was editing your code, so decided to go by ur methodology

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your jquery code inside [Document.ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) function, this will ensure  Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

```
$(function(){
       //Your code here
});
```

Also remove the duplicate Jquery reference

```
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/key-nav.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>// Not needed
```

Also make sure you are using correct generated Id's or use `Classes` as selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ClientIDMode="Static"` on your asp.net controls. You `Asp.Net` controls rendered with different ids